# ggplot geom_bar continuous colour fill with a separate color based on a conditional

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Here is a reproducible sample data set that has a continuous fill based on `Amount`. As you can see from the sample below, I also have a column in `d` called `flag`. What I want is to be able to visualize `flag` by changing the border color of the bar to the color red.

```
# create reproducible data
library(ggplot2)
d <- read.csv(text='Day,Location,Length,Amount,flag
    1,4,3,1.1,FALSE
    1,3,1,2,FALSE
    1,2,3,4,FALSE
    1,1,3,5,FALSE
    2,0,0,0,FALSE
    3,3,3,1.8,TRUE
    3,2,1,3.54,FALSE
    3,1,3,1.1,FALSE',header=T)
ggplot(d, aes(x = Day, y = Length)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = Amount, order = -Location), stat = "identity")
```

I have experimented with `alpha` and that certainly does flag the desired bar but fails to visualize the data in the way I want:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Day, y = Length)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = Amount, order = -Location, alpha = -flag), stat = "identity")
```

`alpha` when using `-flags` (note `-`)also messes with the legend, which is undesirable.

Using the below command returns an error that I need 2 colour variables, but I only want 1, `red`:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Day, y = Length)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = Amount, order = -Location, alpha = -flag), stat = "identity") + 
scale_colour_manual(values = alpha(c('red')))
```

To recap:

1. I want to show the bar where `flag = TRUE` with a red outline (or something equally as noticeable) without changing the continuous scale already decided by `Amount`.
2. I want the legend to reflect that `flag = TRUE` with the colour red (or whatever matches).

I was not able to find an applicable solution perusing the web so any thoughts or suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `colour=flag` (`colour` is the outline in a `geom_bar` while fill is the fill). Then add `+ scale_colour_manual(values=c(NA, 'red'))` where `NA` is used if `flag` is false (no border) and 'red' is used if `flag` is true.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = Day, y = Length)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = Amount, order = -Location, col=flag), stat = "identity") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c(NA, 'red'))
```

(Note: instead you could `geom_bar(aes(...), col=ifelse(d$flag, 'red', NA))` and skip the `scale_colour_manual` but then you don't get a legend).

[image]

If you want to increase the border width, add a `lwd=<new line width>` in your `geom_bar` (outside the `aes`).

Comment: That is perfect. Don't know if you added that second part as an edit or not, but either way you read my mind! Thanks for the quick turnaround and simple solution!