# How to make all values below a threshold have single color with scale continuous?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to map a variable to a continuous color scale, but if the value is a below a certain threshold, it should have a specific color. In this example, I would like to make all car models with an `mpg < 20` filled with gray, and everything above with the continuous color scale:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- head(mtcars)
dat$model <- head(colnames(mtcars))
dat$is_low <- ifelse(dat$mpg < 20, TRUE, FALSE)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = model, y = mpg, fill = mpg)) +
    geom_col()
```

Is that even possible? The closest I have seen is this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31601094/1274242) but it maps a second variably to `scale_color` and not to `scale_fill_continuous`

Comment: The simplest way would be to specify `fill = ifelse(mpg < 20, NA, mpg)`. You can control the colour of the `NA` values with `scale_fill_continuous(na.value = "green")`.

Comment: If you put that as an answer I will upvote it :) I still haven't decide if I will use your or @Jon Spring solution, but this is great!

Comment: Perhaps even simpler: I think you can use `limits` in `scale_fill_continuous`, something like: `scale_fill_continuous(limits = c(20, max(dat$mpg)))`. The default out-of-bounds (`oob`) argument is `oob_censor()`, which "replaces out of bounds values with `NA`" (here, those below 20), and then `na.value` kicks in. My very naive understanding of `scales::oob_censor`, led me to think that also `scale_fill_continuous(oob = oob_censor(mpg, range = c(20, Inf)))` may work. Nope. @teunbrand, suppose you know this function better.. :)

Comment: Well yes I know the function pretty well since I've edited that very function in a PR to the scales package :) The `oob` argument takes a function. That function is then internally supplied with `x` and a `range` parameter, wherein `oob_censor` replaces out-of-bounds values with `NA`. So effectively, your first solution does what your second solution attempts to do, because `oob_censor()` is the default `oob` for continuous scales. You can also supply limits as `c(20, NA)` to have the `NA` replaced by the natural upper limit of the data.

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks a lot for taking your time to clarify! Sloppy RTFM from my side; note to self: `oob` _only_ takes a function name (and _not_ the actual function with arguments, as in my naive attempt...). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant, but you could add a layer that's filtered to just the ones you want gray:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = model, y = mpg, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_col(data = dat[dat$is_low,], fill = "gray70")
```

[image]

Comment: It works great. I will have to see if I use it, or @teunbrand's, depends a bit on the implementation for my real use case, but this is very good. I keep forgetting that in `ggplot` it's always possible to overlay things.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second layer of `geom_col()` where you either color each bar grey or skip if it doesn't meet your criteria. You may also want to change the limits of your coloring scale for the first layer.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = model, y = mpg, fill = mpg)) +
  geom_col() + geom_col(fill=ifelse(dat$mpg < 20, 'gray', NA))
```

Comment: Actually changing the limits will mean anything outside the range would be gray, so just add `+ scale_fill_continuous(limits=c(20,max(dat$mpg)))`